# Вывод детальной картинки

Tags: php, битрикс

Добрый день! Как вывести вместо preview-картинки детальную в списке новостей?
Код шаблона списка новостей:

```
<img class="detail_picture" src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"/>
```

Код шаблона детальной новости:

```
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"])):?>
        <img class="detail_picture" border="0" src="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" width="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>" height="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>" alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>"  title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" />
    <?endif?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код вывода:

```
<img src="<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']?>">
```

А в настройках компонента списка новостей в разделе **Источник данных**, в пункте **Поля** выберите «Детальная картинка»:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]